# VS2022 Coded UI Tests: failing with message Class not registered

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I've built a coded UI test project and I'm trying to run a coded UI test from Test explorer
launched from VS2022 which is running as administrator.
I am facing an issue while running the test as it fails at calling `Playback.Initialize()`with this inner exception :

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
> {8C8700A1-80B2-4BF3-9AD6-1900CE040D7C} failed due to the following
> error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
>
> The following package failed to load: local
> path..\net48\CUITPlugins\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.IE.dll

Any suggestions how to fix this?